# Is there any way to load document in Read only mode?

Tags: docusignapi

We want to show to uploaded pdf file as Read only i.e. Finish button is disabled, sign button is disabled.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found it, EnvelopeRecipients: createEnvelopeRecipientPreview

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/createEnvelopeRecipientPreview#recipientPreviewRequest